# Is this a TabLayout or BottomNav or something else?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

I was trying to add [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppzBi.jpg) view in my app but I do not have any idea what it is.It has more than 10 tabs in it.
Is it a BottomNav or Tablayout? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried using recycleview but I was not satisfied with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be achieved using a recyclerview. This gives the User Experience  of a bottom bar but it is not actually a bottombar (technically).

Comment: Do you know any other ways to implement this view? And how would I make it scrollable?

Comment: To make it scrollable you will have to use a RecyclerView with Horizontal Layout Manager.

Im afraid Sumit, in my opinion this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for scrollable bottom Navigation view in that case, please check this library

https://github.com/DaouMobile/ScrollBottomNavigationView?ref=androidexample365.com